# Как отправить массив ID через GET в битриксе?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, битрикс

Есть у меня радиобаттоны

```
<fieldset class="filter-section">
                    <input type="radio" id="sect-id-4107" name="sect-id" value="19154,18495">
                    <label for="sect-id-4107">Шапочки</label>

                    <input type="radio" id="sect-id-4125" name="sect-id" value="4125">
                    <label for="sect-id-4125">Набородники</label>
          
                    <input type="radio" id="sect-id-4120" name="sect-id" value="4120">
                    <label for="sect-id-4120">Маски</label>
          
                    <input type="radio" id="sect-id-4171" name="sect-id" value="4171">
                    <label for="sect-id-4171">Экраны</label>
                </fieldset>
```

Передаю так

```
$('#perchatkarf-filter').on('change', function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'ajax/index.php?ID='+$('input[name="sect-id"]:checked').val(),
                        type: 'GET',
                        beforeSend: function(){
                            $('#contentTest').css( "filter", "opacity(0.2)" );
                        },
                        success: function(res){
                            $('#contentTest').empty();
                            $('#contentTest').append(res);
                            $('#contentTest').css( "filter", "opacity(1)" );
                        },
                        error: function(){
                            alert('Error!');
                        }
                    });
                });
```

пытаюсь так

```
"ELEMENT_ID" => [$_GET["ID"]],
```

либо же пытаюсь через

```
GLOBALS['arrFilterFav'] = array('ID' => [$_GET["ID"]]);
```

В итоге если в value="1,2"

то он берет только 1 число как мне сделать чтобы попадали все ID ?

Comment: ```"ELEMENT_ID" => explode(',', $_GET["ID"]),```

Comment: неа, мне передовать надо "ELEMENT_ID" => [1,2,3],

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Ты как выбираешь 2 варианта? input с типом radio нужен для выбора одного варианта из списка. Нельзя выбрать два! Если надо несколько, то используй checkbox вместо radio
2. Атрибут name всем сделай sect-id[] вместо sect-id.
3. Данные лучше отправлять с помощью POST.
4. Добавь CSRF поле, почитай что это. В битрикс оно в BX.bitrix_sessid()
5. Значения бери из формы так:

   'ajax/index.php?'+$("#my-form").serialize()